# Colouring variables using scale_colour_manual in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I used the code below to plot my data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Pi, value, color = variable)) + 
geom_point(shape=4) + geom_line() + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c('pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'pink', 'orange'))
```

I can't post images of my plot yet so my data (in long format) looks like this:

```
      Pi   variable    value
    0.4038   X1      2.778755e-01
             .
             .
             .
    0.7782   X10     3.455836e-01
             .
    0.0023   Sqi     5.654000e+00
```

In my code I have manually set the colour for the variable 'X1' to 'X10' (as pink) and for 'Sqi' (as orange) as they fall in that order in `df`.

Eventually I want to add 'X1' to 'X100' variables (each with 50 values), all with the same colour except the 'Sqi' variable.
Any clues as to how I could shorten my code rather than mention 'pink' a hundred times over?

Additionally, it would be helpful if I could specify the variables for which I want a `geom_line()`.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you want to create another column in order to specify colours. You'd create two categories (e.g., pink and orange) and use the column when you specify colour in ggplot.

Comment: Oh and simply change `colour = colourcolumn`?

Any clue about the `geom_line()` problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the comment of @jazzurro, to adjust line colors and size (or linetype), you can do something like this.  You have to make sure your color and size variables are factors or you will get an error: `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`

```
x <- c(1:3, 4:6)
y <- c(3:5, 8:10)
line.col <- c("pink", "orange", "blue")
width <- c(2, 3, 5)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, line.col=line.col, width = width)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color = line.col, size = factor(width))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = line.col) +
  scale_size_manual(values = df$width)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that lawyeR, but considering I have variables X1 to X100 and Sqi, I wanted a more efficient way to tell R to colour these variables, rather than mention the colour in `line.col <- c()`.
Which is similar to coding it under `scale_colour_manual`

Comment: You can use rep() to make the code compact for your 100 variables?

Comment: Oh that did the trick! Thanks a ton! I'm new to stack so how can I indicate that your `rep()` comment is the answer?

Comment: Excellent, and glad to help.  Click on the up arrow by my answer to accept it.  Tx

Comment: lawyeR, any clues how to have lines for some variables and just points for the other? tweaking `geom_line()`